# "rvm rubygems current" vs "rvm update --system" vs "gem update rubygems-update"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm

A bit confused about how to go about updating rubygems. Process keeps changing (or at least I get conflicting information from the interwebs).

```
$ gem outdated
rubygems-update (1.8.10 < 1.8.11)
sass (3.1.8 < 3.1.10)

$ rvm gemset use global
$ gem outdated 
rubygems-update (1.8.10 < 1.8.11)
```

Now, in the past I'd use `rvm update --system` to install the `rubygems-update` then switch back to my working gemset (*from* `global`) and upgrade the rest of the gems.

But, recently, I switched to using `rvm rubygems current` as per the [RVM site](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/) but, as of this writing, **rvm** doesn't know about `rubygems-update 1.8.11`. So, what to do?  Site says I could use `rvm rubygems head` but I'm a bit afraid (irrationally?) of grabbing the development branch.

Can someone who knows more about this than I chime in and either alleviate my fears or tell me how you approach rvm & rubygems when they fall out of sync...as it seems to be happening more an more...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update RVM to latest development version:

```
rvm get head
```

or to stable version:

```
rvm get stable
```

update rubygems to latest available:

```
rvm rubygems latest
```

or just a version:

```
rvm rubygems 1.8.16
```

rubygems is installed per ruby not per gemset, so it is not possible to have different rubygems in different gemsets